# Rounding a float to the nearest integer in ruby

Tags: ruby

If i have a float of 49.967 and I do .to_i it will chop it down to 49 which for my use of disk space analysis .967 is over 900mb of space that wont be accounted for in the displays.

Is there a function to round numbers to the nearest integer or would i have to define it my self like this:

```
class Float
  def to_nearest_i
    (self+0.5).to_i
  end
end
```

so that i could then do:

```
>> 5.44.to_nearest_i
=> 5
>> 5.54.to_nearest_i
=> 6
```

Comment: You know there's doc for Ruby, right? http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Float.html#M000532

Comment: @glennmcdonald, your link is broken. Here is a new link for 2.20: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html

Comment: and here is a link to [Float.round](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Try `Float.round`.

```
irb(main):001:0> 5.44.round
=> 5
irb(main):002:0> 5.54.round
=> 6
```