# Dropping decimal point

Tags: ruby

I need to compare a data set in which one batch of data came with currency with decimals such as 246.54 the new data removes the decimals, does not round up, and has just 246... so I need to remove the decimals from the first batch so I can compare. How would I do this without rounding up?

Comment: `(246.54).to_i` not sufficient?

Comment: Before you accept an answer, think about what you expect to happen with negative numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the floor function.  It gives the first integer smaller than or equal to whatever number you feed it.

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > i = 246.54
  => 246.54 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > i.floor
  => 246
```

Comment: So what do you do? Check if it's negative, then turn positive, floor and turn negative again? Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 1):

```
if mynumber >= 0 then 
    mynumber = mynumber.floor
else
    mynumber = 0 - mynumber
    mynumber = mynumber.floor
    mynumber = 0 - mynumber
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do a rounding in ruby:

`246.54 .to_nearest_i`

Comment: He said he didn't want to round up, though.  Also, that to_nearest_i function doesn't exist unless you define it yourself as with something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346205/rounding-a-float-to-the-nearest-integer-in-ruby